# Whats wrong with this SQL query? Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

And the error im getting is

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = (tick)TESTKEY(tick)'**

```
SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key = 'TESTKEY';
```

I tried this site but it isn't much help. http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/
As well as with ticks and apostrophe.

Comment: How was i supposed to know it was a reserved word? thanks for the downvotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SQL passes the syntax check at the link you provided:

```
SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = 'TESTKEY';
```